# Git issues regarding pull and push

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a private bitbucket repo and it seems like git pull just hangs there and does nothing. I have the right ssh-keys added for the right email and everything worked well until last days. I can't figure it out why git pull and push just hangs there and never stops. Does anyone encountered this kind of issue ?

Also, if this helps, I can't even do yarn install ( I have a private repo in the package.json of my project as well ). So i guess it's a issue regarding the creds, but i have the right ssh-key that's why I don't understand what it's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering [BitBucket status](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/) is clear, if your private repository is hosted on bitbucket.org, it might be a network issue on your side.

Check first if [`ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` does work](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html#TroubleshootSSHissues-TestSSHauthentication), meaning if you see "logged in as xxx".